# select2 загрузка страницы при введений символов в поле ввода

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, select2

select2.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#user_ids').select2({
        allowClear : true,
        ajax: {
            url: '/user/select-by-userId',
            dataType: 'json',
            delay : 500,
        }
    }).on('select2:select', function (e) {
        var data = e.params.data;
        $("#user_ids_selected").val(data.text)
    })
});
```

search.blade.php

```
@push('scripts')
    <script src="{{ asset('jmart-admin/scripts/select2/select2.js') }}"></script>
@endpush

 <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                {{ Form::dropdownList('user_ids',
                    [
                        $request->get('user_ids') => $request->get('user_ids_selected')
                    ],
                    $request->get('user_ids'),
                    [
                        'id' => 'user_ids',
                    ],
                    [
                        'label' => $request->label('user_ids')
                    ],
                ) }}
            </div>

            <div>
                {{ Form::inputHidden('user_ids_selected', $request->get('user_ids_selected'), ['id' => 'user_ids_selected']) }}
            </div>
```

при вводе данных в поле ввода происходит поиск, и во время поиска в странице появляется загрузка. как убрать?

Comment: Проблема то в чем? Как должно быть?

Comment: при ajax запросе происходит загрузка страницы, это как оказалось blockUI плагин,который блокирует страницу при запросах. Ищу как отключить